# Where are jQuery UI colors and widget styles set?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

When you download jQuery UI from the jQuery web site, you get a file of javascript code and a file of css code.

I understand that CSS code has to do with various elements of the style and appearance of various web page elements.

I would like to know if there is anything having to do with the style of the jQuery elements that is part of the jQuery UI javascript code.  Can I rip and replace the css file to change the style of the jQuery elements on my web site, or are there some parts of the style hard-coded into the javascript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of it is hard coded in the javascript files.  If you were to remove the CSS, your widgets will lose all styling, including positioning.

jQuery UI uses a [css framework](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API).  You can freely edit these files to change the look and feel of the theme-rolled elements, but good luck!  A lot of the classes are interdependent.  On the other hand, jQuery UI adds all needed classes to the elements when the widgets are activated, so as long as you dive in and learn what's going on, you should be able to figure things out.

I would recommend using the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to get the styles as close as possible to what you want, and then tweaking the css from there.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is only for styling. If you need a different styling you can adjust the CSS. It's just there to make your life easier....